# Are GDMs faster than CDMs in starting Xorg?

Tags: xorg, display-manager

I suppose since graphical display managers already launch Xorg, they would just have to re-initiate it rather than launching it from the start like `startx` does.

So in that case does Xorg completely restart or takes over the display manager, and so it is faster?

Comment: Could you explain *"So in that case does Xorg completely restart or takes over the display manager, and so it is faster?"* in more details? This question is hard to parse and understand.

Comment: Display managers launch an Xorg instance when they start. Is that instance reused again (taking over the place of display manager) or killed completely and launched from the beginning?

Comment: IIRC this used to be configurable in GDM - you could set it to reuse the X session for the first login, or start a new session for each login. Not sure if when they removed that option, though.